# Weex failed to render in Fragment

Tags: android, weex

I am new to Weex and I need to render Weex in a Fragment in Android. But, it failed with the error:

> Unexpected token '}'. Cannot parse statement.

I tried to search the clue like: [ISSUE:How to load Weex into Fragment](https://github.com/alibaba/weex/issues/2593) but I found no solution.

The output log is below:

```
08-13 12:16:36.306 20983-20983 E/JL: [ main: 
(WeexPageFragment.java:59) loadWeex ] - 
renderhttp://172.16.43.62:8080/dist/hello.js
08-13 12:16:36.306 20983-20983 D/WXSDKInstance: Start render page: 
08-13 12:16:36.308 20983-21003 D/weex: createInstance >>>> 
instanceId:1, options:{}, data:
callJS >>>> instanceId:1function:createInstance
08-13 12:16:36.342 20983-21003 D/jsLog: [JS Framework] COMPATIBILITY 
WARNING: Weex DSL 1.0 (.we) framework is no longer supported! It will 
be removed in the next version of WeexSDK, your page would be crash if 
you still using the ".we" framework. Please upgrade it to Vue.js or 
Rax.__ERROR
08-13 12:16:36.360 20983-21003 E/jsengine:  ReportException : 
Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Cannot parse statement.
at (global function):8
Function@[native code]
Function@[native code]
(weex framework):1:148499
ei@(weex framework):1:148517
createInstance@(weex framework):1:151735
(weex framework):1:255299
08-13 12:16:36.360 20983-21003 E/weex: reportJSException >>>> 
instanceId:1, exception function:createInstance, exception:Exception: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Cannot parse statement.
at (global function):8
Function@[native code]
Function@[native code]
(weex framework):1:148499
ei@(weex framework):1:148517
createInstance@(weex framework):1:151735
(weex framework):1:255299
```

Comment: Does the weex bundle even render at all? (using the weex playground for example)

Comment: @Neps Hi Neps,the playground rendered successfully  and  implementation with Activity also rendered,too.  My case here is  the `WXSDKInstance` instance can not be created,which is the 1st step to render a weex page.
And glad to hear your reply : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem(caused by called wrong method).

And for those who need a demo to see *How to render Weex page in Fragment* try this [weex-start-kit](https://github.com/w11p3333/weex-start-kit/tree/master/Android/Demo)

Answer (score 0):

The `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'` is quite a common error when parsing or executing incomplete js code. Maybe the js bundle of your page is not fully downloaded before rendering.

Comment: Dear Hanks,finally i make it to render weex page in Android Fragment.
The mistake is i used wrong method to load the url ~~mWXSDKInstance.render()~~ instead of the correct `mWXSDKInstance.renderByUrl()`,Thanks for your help :)